# Не выводятся значения параметров введенных с клавиатуры. Конструкторы

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с проблемой, что моя программа не хочет выводить значения Name в 78 и 79 строках, почему? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
private:
    int probeg; //модель машины
    int cost; //стоимость машины
    string Name;
public:
    Car() {
        //конструктор без параметров
        probeg = 3050;
        cost = 39589;
        Name = "Cherry";
        cout << " Конструктор без параметров\n";
        cout << " Создан объект Автомобиль: " << Name << " Пробег: " << probeg << ". Стоимость " << cost << "$" << endl << endl;
    }
    Car(int probeg, int cost, string Name) {
        //конструктор с параметрами
        this->probeg = probeg;
        this->cost = cost;
        cout << " Конструктор с параметрами\n";
        cout << " Создан объект Автомобиль: " << Name << " Пробег: " << this->probeg << ". Стоимость " << this->cost << "$" << endl << endl;
    }
    Car(Car& c) {
        //конструктор копирования
        probeg = c.probeg; cost = c.cost;
        cout << " Конструктор копирования\n";
        cout << " Создан объект Автомобиль: " << Name << " Пробег: " << probeg << " модели. Стоимость " << cost << "$" << endl << endl;
    }
    Car(int a) {
        //конструктор преобразования
        probeg = a; cost = a; Name = "Cherry";
        cout << " Конструктор преобразования\n";
        cout << " Создан объект Автомобиль: " << Name << " Пробег: " << probeg << " модели. Стоимость " << cost << "$" << endl << endl;
    }

    ~Car() {}

    Car& operator +() {
        probeg += 5000;
        return *this;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << "   " << probeg << endl;
    }
    void displayN() {
        cout << "   " << Name << endl;
    }
    bool operator <(const Car& secondAuto) {
        return (probeg < secondAuto.probeg);
    }
    bool operator !=(const Car& SecondName) {
        return (Name != SecondName.Name);
    }
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    string Name;

    cout << "Name ";
    cin >> Name;
    Car c1(100, 200, Name);

    cout << "Name ";
    cin >> Name;
    Car c2(300, 400, Name);

    cout << " ----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << " Названия первого и второго автомобилей:\n ";
    c1.displayN();
    c2.displayN();
    cout << " ----------------------------------------\n";

    if (c2 != c1) {
        cout << "\n Названия автомобилей не равны." << endl << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "\n Названия автомобилей равны." << endl << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добавьте что-то на подобие: this->Name = "что-то", в тех местах, где у вас проблемы

Comment: Что значит "не хочет выводить значения"??? У вас все прекрасно выводится, только значения `Name` у вас - пустые строки. Вот и выводятся пустые строки.

Comment: Всё правильно выводит - пустую строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решён, всем спасибо! По советам сделал следующее: добавил после 25 строчки this->Name = Name; и добавил в 27 строку перед Name часть кода this->

Answer (score 1):

Так Ваши конструкторы не инициализируют член Name.